# HP Notebook fan not controlled

Tags: 22.04, hp, fan

The sensor software displays a fan speed of 0, as shown in the following figure:

[image: fan speed]

It's a HP Victus by HP Gaming Laptop 16-r0xx. The fan cannot be controlled using the fancontrol software, even though its services are running in the background. The equipment fan always maintains a constant speed, so that the temperature is always prone to increase. I am unable to adjust the fan speed through BIOS.
The processor is 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700HX, display card is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU，fan is hp-wmi/fan.

Comment: Did you do `sudo sensors-detect` ?

Comment: Yes,but it can't scan the fan normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop is not compatible with Linux.
HP does not provide Linux drivers for many of it's new laptops (including the gaming ones). The fans speed is controlled to some extent when CPU temp rises. You can try newer kernel versions and wait until some developer (maybe yourself) adds your laptop's driver to the kernel. I'm also using an older HP gaming laptop and there is no fan control yet, kernel 6.6 though keeps the system cooler and fans are better controlled (more sensors work on newer kernel).

Comment: OK,thank you for your answer.